# uploadify scriptData parameters not showing up at server

Tags: post, uploadify, scriptdata

I have the following code (simplified) that uploadify seems ok with (when calling methods), but the scriptData parameters never appear at the host (nothing visible via $_POST).

`params = '{ "A":"aye",' + "\n" + '"B" : "Bee" }'
$("#file_upload").uploadifySettings("scriptData", params);
$("#file_upload").uploadifyUpload();`

Is there something wrong with the way I'm formating the params variable, or anything else? I've been messing with this for hours...frustrating! (We need more examples in the doc :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after scratching my head for awhile found out that scriptData ([See Uploadify Documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/scriptdata/)) takes an actual object NOT a string representation of the JSON object.  Therefore, you need to get rid of the single quotes around your object.